# How to create a class after every single element dragged and dropped?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to put in place a system that works like this : you have the choice between 5 elements of a list to drag and drop in a special place. Once you've dropped it, a pop up appears that asks you in what you want to change the element. Then the element modified appears in the special place.

It works once, but if you want to add another element, this new elements deletes the old one to take its place.

I'm trying to add a class each time something gets dropped so that nothing gets deleted (so you'll have classes named dropped1, dropped2, dropped3, etc), but somehow, it doesn't seem to change anything and I can't figure out why.

Anyway, here's the code :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#allFacets').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul',
    delay: 150,
    helper: "clone",
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    start: function(e, ui) {
      ui.item.show(); // force jquery ui to display the original
    }
  });
  $('#userFacets').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul',
    delay: 150,
    helper: "clone",
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    receive: function(e, ui) {
      ui.item.clone().appendTo(this); // append a copy
      $("#userFacets.userFacets.ui-sortable").each(function(i){
          $(this).addClass("received"+ (i+1));
      });
      var step = prompt("Choose a name");
      $(this).html(step);
      ui.sender.sortable("cancel"); // return the original
    }
  }).on("dblclick", "li", function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.facet-container {
  width: 330px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
p {
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 1em;
}
.facet-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 143px;
  min-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}
.facet-list li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
.facet-list li.placeholder {
  height: 1.2em
}
.facet {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  cursor: move;
}
.facet.ui-sortable-helper {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.placeholder {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background-color: #fffffd;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="facet-container">
  <div class="left">
    <label>All Facets</label>
    <ul id="allFacets" class="facet-list">
      <li class="facet">Facet 2</li>
      <li class="facet">Facet 3</li>
      <li class="facet">Facet 5</li>
      <li class="facet">Facet 1</li>
      <li class="facet">Facet 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <label>User Facets</label>
    <ul id="userFacets" class="facet-list">

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Drag & drop to rearrange items within a list or between lists.</br>Double-click to move item from one list to the bottom of the other.</p>
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the edited JS

```js
$(function() {
  $('#allFacets').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul',
    delay: 150,
    helper: "clone",
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    start: function(e, ui) {
      ui.item.show(); // force jquery ui to display the original
    }
  });
  $('#userFacets').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul',
    delay: 150,
    helper: "clone",
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    receive: function(e, ui) {
      var step = prompt("Choose a name");
      $(this).append("<li class='facet'>" + step + "</li>")
      ui.sender.sortable("cancel"); // return the original
    }
  }).on("dblclick", "li", function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.facet-container {
  width: 330px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
p {
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 1em;
}
.facet-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 143px;
  min-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}
.facet-list li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
.facet-list li.placeholder {
  height: 1.2em
}
.facet {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  cursor: move;
}
.facet.ui-sortable-helper {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.placeholder {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background-color: #fffffd;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="facet-container">
  <div class="left">
    <label>All Facets</label>
    <ul id="allFacets" class="facet-list">
      <li class="facet">Facet 2</li>
      <li class="facet">Facet 3</li>
      <li class="facet">Facet 5</li>
      <li class="facet">Facet 1</li>
      <li class="facet">Facet 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <label>User Facets</label>
    <ul id="userFacets" class="facet-list">

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Drag & drop to rearrange items within a list or between lists.</br>Double-click to move item from one list to the bottom of the other.</p>
```